# How to reset Logitech mouse's back/forward buttons?

Tags: macos, mouse

I've been using my Logitech Anywhere MX with my Mac succesfully for a couple of months, but suddenly last week the functionality of the back/forward buttons changed from navigating to previous/next page in history to switching to next/previous tab in Chrome. How can I restore the previous functionality?

I've already checked the Logitech Control Center, and there the buttons are still defined as back and forward.

Note: If I remember correctly, the buttons have never worked in Finder.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. I would change the settings to something different and then back. You could also try uninstalling/reinstalling the Logitech software.

Comment: Tried this, but it didn't help. Also, the current Logitech installer has no separate uninstaller anymore, so it's uncertain how completely I managed to remove the software. Found a temporary fix by binding the buttons to keystrokes, `option+[` and `option+]` work in most apps I've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, I found no other solution except changing the buttons to send the corresponding keystrokes. Fortunately, this works fine in almost every app I frequently use, including Finder.

The keystrokes I used were `command+option+8` for back and `command+option+9` for forward. Note that this is on a Finnish keyboard layout.

Comment: Where do you map the mouse buttons?? What do you need to open? Where are the settings for that?

Comment: I think I did it in Logitech Control Center, but it’s been over 4 years so the options may have changed since.